# iPhone AddressBook - how to create a new record with app from my App

Tags: iphone, new-operator, record, abaddressbook

I'm trying to create a new record of Person thru my App. I have the name, email and phone nr.
How can i pass them to the modal view of newPerson?
I'm following Apple's docs, but i'm stuck.
I'm using a ABNewPersonViewController. Is that correct? How do I fill the fields in the modal view?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display something in the ABNewPersonViewController, you have to create and set up an ABRecordRef for the properties you want to pre-fill and then set the displayedPerson property on ABNewPersonViewController. So a simple example may be:

```
- (void)createNewPerson
{
  // Create the pre-filled properties
  ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
  CFErrorRef error = NULL;
  ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR("John"), &error);
  ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, CFSTR("Smith"), &error);
  NSAssert( !error, @"Something bad happened here." );

  // Create and set-up the new person view controller
  ABNewPersonViewController* newPersonViewController = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  [newPersonViewController setDisplayedPerson:newPerson];
  [newPersonViewController setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];

  // Wrap in a nav controller and display
  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonViewController];
  [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

  // Clean up everything
  [navController release];
  [newPersonViewController release];
  CFRelease(newPerson);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. To add a phone number, how can i do it? CFSTR does not work. What's the equivalent do integer?

Answer (score 11):

if you already have the details and you just want to write them to the address book then you don't need the - ABNewPersonViewController.
the ABNewPersonViewController is used for letting the user to add record to the address book with the common controller of the iphone address book.

instead you should do the following:

a) add the address book () frame work to your app.

b) import the address book headers to your view.

c) create an addressbook instanse and a new record:

```
ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
     ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
```

d) for single value properties you use:

```
  ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR("Katie"), nil);
  ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, CFSTR("Bell"), nil);
```

e)for the multy value properties such as phone number / mail you use:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, @"054-5429920", kABHomeLabel, NULL);

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,@"02-9809878", kABWorkLabel, NULL); 

    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);
    CFRelease(multiPhone);


        ABMutableMultiValueRef multiEmail = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail, @"shannoga@me.com", kABHomeLabel, NULL);

    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty, multiEmail, &error);
    CFRelease(multiEmail);
```

f) save the changes to the address book, none of the code you wrote wond take effect with out this:

```
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, newPerson, nil);
    BOOL didAdd = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil);
```

g) relese the record and the address book and check if the record addaed:

```
CFRelease(newPerson);
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    NSLog(@"didAdd = %d",didAdd);
```

thats all
good luck
hope it helped

shani

Comment: great, correct! (If you add CFErrorRef error = NULL; it's perfect!)