# Adding a new phone number into contact app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have this code to open the contacts view controller:

```
ABNewPersonViewController *newPersonVC = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
               newPersonVC.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
               UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonVC];
               [self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

I want to be able to grab `NSString *phoneNumber = @"(416)-555-5555";` and put it into the "home phone" field. I have looked [through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377441/how-to-create-contacts-in-address-book-in-iphone-sdk) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249010/objective-c-adding-a-contact-to-a-specific-group-in-the-iphone) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735977/iphone-add-contact-to-existing-group-in-addressbook) and I end up getting either nothing popping up or my app crashes. Apple's documentation doesn't help much either.

How do I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to add a new number to the existing contact in the contact app?? Are you doing this only??

Comment: I want to make a new contact altogether.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484481/iphone-addressbook-how-to-create-a-new-record-with-app-from-my-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"(416)-555-5555";
ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonDepartmentProperty,(__bridge  CFTypeRef)@"Department", nil);
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue,(__bridge  CFTypeRef)phoneNumber, kABWorkLabel, nil);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
NSAssert( !error, @"Something bad happened here." );

ABNewPersonViewController *newPersonVC = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[newPersonVC setDisplayedPerson:newPerson];
newPersonVC.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonVC];
[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

Hope it Help's you.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your help; this has been very frustrating. Such a shame that it has to be this difficult for Apple to update and modernize the code.

Comment: Just curious though: what's the code for adding a phone number to an existing contact?

Comment: ABAddressBookRef addressbook =  ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *people = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressbook, CFSTR("ContactName"));
    if ((people != NULL) && [people count]) {
        ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:0];
        ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc]init];
        picker.personViewDelegate = self;
        picker.displayedPerson = person;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    CFRelease(addressbook);